# Mmlogic Traffic light

Tags: javascript, css

So, I'm using this program called **MMLogic** and I have a question about a school project.

We had to create a traffic light using a button, and everytime we pressed the button It'd switch colour and at the 4th press reset.

So a truth table would be:

```
+----------+------+
|   Red    | 001  |
+----------+------+
|  Yellow  | 010  |
+----------+------+
|  Green   | 011  |
+----------+------+
|  Reset   | 100  |
+----------+------+
```

Now, I have done that but the next assignment is to create 4 traffic lights as in a junction, so:
Traffic light A would be green at the same time as light B, and C & D will be red. All cycling through at the press of one button.

Truth table ->

```
+--------+----------+---------------+-------+---------+
| Press  |  binary  |  state AB/CD  |  AB   |   CD    |
+--------+----------+---------------+-------+---------+
|   0.   |   000    |  red/green    |  100  |   001   |
|   1.   |   001    |  red/orange   |  100  |   010   |
|   2.   |   010    |  green/red    |  001  |   100   |
|   3.   |   011    |  orange/red   |  010  |   100   |
|   4.   |   100    |    reset      |       |         |
+--------+----------+---------------+-------+---------+
```

So, I can use any gates, from `AND` to `XOR` and more.

Can somebody help me with this assignment...
I've worked on it for 3 periods now and still can't figure it out...

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you only have 3 colors, why use 3 bits to do the job? Just use 2 bits, look: red -> 001, green -> 010, orange -> 011, so, if AB ==  001 and AB & CD == 0: binary is 000, else: binary is the value of AB. I don't know if it's helpful, good luck. BTW it seems your problem seems not related to css and javascript...